Debian 12.7 installed on a USB key works on Intel CPU but not AMD: grub is never loaded
I installed Debian 12 (amd64 arch since I used debian-12.7.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso) on a USB key, by using a computer with an Intel CPU (Core i7 3770K). I configured the "BIOS" to UEFI-only.
I can boot Debian on this system with no issue: I see GRUB, it has a timeout before starting Debian, and then the system boots.
But when I plug this USB key on a computer with an AMD CPU (Ryzen 7 5800X), it never boots: I can select that Debian instance from the boot menu, but when I press Enter it returns back to that screen. After 2 tries, it only shows a black screen. It never reaches the GRUB screen.
Both systems are configured as UEFI-only and secure boot is disabled.
Are some drivers missing? To my knowledge, Debian (and Linux) are portable: we can move a storage with a Linux system to another computer and boot it without any issue, as long as they have the same architecture.
Test with the Intel CPU
Boot menu:

Storage and partitions:
root@serveur:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 7.46 GiB, 8014528512 bytes, 15653376 sectors
Disk model: Freecom Databar 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F3F8597A-E3A9-4340-B561-976463C941D7

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 13941248 12890625  6.1G Linux filesystem

root@serveur:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  724K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       6.0G  2.0G  3.7G  35% /
tmpfs           7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       511M  5.9M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000

root@serveur:~# tree /boot/efi/
/boot/efi/
└── EFI
    └── debian
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── fbx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── mmx64.efi
        └── shimx64.efi

3 directories, 6 files

root@serveur:~# ls -lh /boot/efi/EFI/debian/
total 5.9M
-rwx------ 1 root root  108 Oct 16 21:58 BOOTX64.CSV
-rwx------ 1 root root  86K Oct 16 21:58 fbx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root  126 Oct 16 21:58 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 4.1M Oct 16 21:58 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 831K Oct 16 21:58 mmx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 938K Oct 16 21:58 shimx64.efi

root@serveur:~# efibootmgr -v 
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* debian    HD(1,GPT,84ba4a07-f69b-4768-a2c6-841363bcaa45,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)

root@serveur:~$ cat /etc/fstab
[…]
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=ce54e770-e3ba-44a0-8dd1-5b9308e18eac /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=B2A6-2FC0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

root@serveur:~# lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid 
NAME   MOUNTPOINT LABEL  SIZE UUID
sda                      7,5G 
├─sda1 /boot/efi  BOOT   512M B2A6-2FC0
└─sda2 /                 6,1G ce54e770-e3ba-44a0-8dd1-5b9308e18eac

Check that UEFI mode is used:
root@serveur:~# ls -lh /sys/firmware/efi
total 0
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4.0K Oct 18 19:25 config_table
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Aug 25 19:35 efivars
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4.0K Oct 18 19:25 fw_platform_size
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4.0K Oct 18 19:25 fw_vendor
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Oct 18 19:25 mok-variables
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4.0K Oct 18 19:25 runtime
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    0 Oct 18 19:25 runtime-map
-r--------  1 root root 4.0K Oct 18 19:25 systab

Test with the AMD CPU
Boot menu:

For some reason the Debian entry starts with UEFI: .
The highlight choice doesn't work: it get back to that screen.
But, there is something interesting: I ran sudo update-grub from my main install (Ubuntu 24.04 that is installed on this computer, as shown above it is on a NVMe SSD):
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) on /dev/sda2
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

It detected Debian 12 and added an entry to my main GRUB (not the one on the USB stick), and I was able to boot Debian 12 without any issue from this GRUB menu.
So it looks like the GRUB on the USB stick only work on the Intel computer. And the Debian itself has no issue when it can be booted by the GRUB on the SSD.

Current status: trying apt install amd64-microcode before moving the USB key again.

Grephical or text install? Just wondering if the different graphics subsystems are throwing you off

@ChrisDavies I did the graphical install. apt install amd64-microcode did no difference, but this is not surprising since it looks like it is used when loading the kernel, but I'm stopped before the GRUB step, when trying to boot on AMD CPU.

OK. I have no other suggestions. Good luck

Installer normally puts an UEFI boot entry into systems UEFI to boot from first drive's ESP, usually internal drive. sudo efibootmgr -v But then other systems will not have that entry. External drives, just  like installer can boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in ESP on external drive. When you installed did you also create an ESP & have boot files in /EFI/Boot and maybe /EFI/grub? And then boot a drive entry, not a grub or Debian entry?

@oldfred I added images and output from both computers, hopefully it will help to understand the issue.

Not sure which install is which on which computer. And 6GB is pretty small for a full install. It should work, but you cannot save much data or add many apps. What is content of /etc/fstab. Is UUID of ESP for the internal drive or the flash drive? And in UEFI one time boot menu, do you have a UEFI:XXX where XXX is name or label of flash drive?

@oldfred The install I have issues with is on the USB stick, data about it is shown in the "Test with the Intel CPU" section. You can ignore the stuff about Ubuntu, it's irrelevant here. (I know the partition is small but that will be enough to use it on a headless server) I added /etc/fstab and lsblk. As shown on the image "UEFI:XXX where XXX is name or label of flash drive" is not displayed.

Is it set for UEFI boot, or is Server very old and BIOS only? Does ESP on flash drive have /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi? As then UEFI boot should offer to boot flash drive by name or label as UEFI:label.

@oldfred Thanks for your help, the directory /EFI/Boot/ is missing, as shown in the output of tree /boot/efi/ (added in question). Is there a way to install it? The motherboard with the Intel CPU uses a beta BIOS that added the UEFI compatibility, maybe it causes issues, even if it has been set to "UEFI only".

did you install grub with the --removable flag?

@td211 I didn't know about this option, I applied it and it works, thanks! I can boot Debian on both computers now. It looks like the --removable flag was exactly what I needed. https://superuser.com/questions/1756758/what-does-grub-installs-removable-flag-do

I believe the removable command does add the /EFI/Boot and ESP partition for external drive boot or fallback boot on internal drive which a few systems seem to default to.

@td211 Please add an answer about the --removable flag.

By default the Debian installer (and probably others) install GRUB without accounting for removable drives. You just need to reinstall GRUB with the --removable flag to make it easily bootable on other PCs.
This has nothing to do with Intel or AMD CPUs (both are x86_64 anyways).

"This has nothing to do with Intel or AMD CPUs (both are x86_64 anyways)." Right, it must be related to the different UEFI boot, due to different motherboards, not the CPU on it. Feel free to share any information you have about why grub worked on one computer but not on another one.

Probably because the Intel system is the one where you did the installation, so it added an EFI boot entry to that system that isn't available on the other one. The --removable flag mitigates this. @A.L

When you installed Debian 12 in UEFI mode, the installer executed grub-install which wrote /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi (and also /boot/efi/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi if Secure Boot support was installed) to the ESP partition of the USB key.
But that's not all it did. It also used the UEFI Runtime Services to store a bit of information, called an UEFI boot variable, to the system NVRAM: the place where BIOS settings are also stored. You can view these UEFI boot variables by using the command efibootmgr -v as root, or by accessing the virtual efivarfs filesystem at /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/.
The UEFI boot variable contains the following pieces of information:

the name of the boot entry, which was debian in your case
the PARTUUID of the EFI System Partition (ESP) that contains the UEFI bootloader
some redundant information for identifying the ESP (disk number, partition start offset, partition length) in case identification by PARTUUID is not successful
the pathname of the bootloader file on the ESP (\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi if Secure Boot support is in use, or \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi if not)

For normal hard disks and SSDs, this is fine. But with removable media like your USB key, this information gets left behind when the USB key is moved from one system to another.
Once the USB key was plugged into your AMD system, that system saw that the key apparently contained a valid ESP partition, and so it displayed UEFI: <product name of the USB key>, Partition 1 in the boot menu. But since the UEFI boot variable data was not transferred over from the Intel system, the system had no way of knowing that it should be loading shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi from the EFI/debian directory of the ESP partition.
For removable media (and for situations when the NVRAM data has been lost), the UEFI specification defines an architecture-specific removable media/fallback boot path which can be used if the system sees a valid-looking ESP partition but has no UEFI boot variables referring to it. For the x86_64 architecture, this boot path is \EFI\boot\bootx64.efi as expressed by the firmware, or /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi as you would see it in Debian.
In other words, to make a removable media UEFI-bootable not just in the system it was created for, but in all UEFI systems it might be plugged into, the bootloader file must have that specific pathname. And grub-install can certainly do that... but only if you specifically ask for it, by using the --removable or --force-extra-removable options. The former option will place the bootloader file only in the removable media/fallback path; the latter one sets up one copy of the bootloader in the normal way, then makes another copy of it in the fallback path.
Unfortunately, the Debian 12 installer does not automatically detect that the OS is being installed to a removable disk, nor prominently offer the option to install the UEFI bootloader to the removable media/fallback path. If you are installing UEFI-bootable Debian 12 to removable media, you will have to know this and do it yourself after the main installation is complete.
After successfully booting from your USB key on your Intel system, you'd need just one command to correct this deficiency:
grub-install --removable


That's a good in depth explanation. I always wondered what was so different between both installation modes.
